# React native replace LisItem to?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a project with a list, but I read that ListItem is deprecated. How can I replace it?

My Page after the updates using the native-base components

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import {
  Container, Header, Content, Card,
  CardItem, Text, Icon, Right,
  Left, Body, Title, Button }
from 'native-base';
import { Avatar } from 'react-native-elements';

class TenantDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='arrow-back' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>My Name</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
        <Content>
          <View style={styles.userRow}>
            <View style={styles.userImage}>
              <Avatar
                rounded
                size="large"
                source={{
                  uri: 'https://myirent.com/rent/appImg/person-icon.png',
                }}
              />
            </View>
            <View>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>Jonh Test</Text>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'gray',
                  fontSize: 16,
                }}
              >
                joinh@gmail.com{'\n'}xxx-xxx-xxxx
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <Card>
            <View style={styles.containerTextHeader}>
              <Text style={styles.infoTextHeader}>Tenant Details</Text>
            </View>
            <CardItem>
              <Icon active name="logo-googleplus" />
              <Text>First Name</Text>
              <Right>
                <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scroll: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  userRow: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingBottom: 8,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    paddingRight: 15,
    paddingTop: 6,
  },
  userImage: {
    marginRight: 12,
  },
  listItemContainer: {
    height: 55,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderColor: '#ECECEC',
  },
  containerTextHeader: {
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingBottom: 12,
    backgroundColor: '#F4F5F4',
  },
  infoTextHeader: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginLeft: 20,
    color: 'gray',
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
});

export default TenantDetails;
```

Thanks. I 'm having issue with the right arrow not align to the right (image below). Also, how can I change the  to have a label and value? So when I click on it, I can open. modal to edit the value

My Screen:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView is deprecated. no ListItem. whoever using list and list item of `native base` can be good choice. here is an example

```js
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { Container, Header, Content, List, ListItem, Text } from 'native-base';
    export default class ListExample extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Container>
            <Header />
            <Content>
              <List>
                <ListItem>
                  <Text>Simon Mignolet</Text>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <Text>Nathaniel Clyne</Text>
                </ListItem>
                <ListItem>
                  <Text>Dejan Lovren</Text>
                </ListItem>
              </List>
            </Content>
          </Container>
        );
      }
    }
```

[result in ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhvFs.png)

You can install native-base package by this command:
`npm install native-base --save`
Or if you use yarn:
`yarn add native-base`

Native base is a free and open source UI component library for React Native to build native mobile apps for iOS and Android platforms. NativeBase also supports web from version 2.4.1.

Comment: Hello, I just added an image of what I am trying to create. I menu with a list of buttons. The buttons will have a name and the value in the right side. If you click on the button, you can edit/add a value. The icons in the left side is nice, but it is not a big deal for me.

Comment: This link is exactly what you need. Thanks `native base!` [native-base-card](https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#card-list-headref)

Comment: That's great! I include an image of how is my screen now. Any reason why the right arrow is not align to the right? Is possible to be able to click on the cardItem and open a modal to edit the content?

Comment: Yes. You can. Wrap card item by  TouchableOpacity or any button and then define its onPress.  If you think my answer helped you, please mark it as best answer. Thanks alot

Comment: It seems your question about arrow icon alignment need to your code. Please post it.

Comment: This is better that you post another question. Because my answer seems unrelated now!

Comment: Just did. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Tnx alot! If there is no problem, after hours, i can answer your question. Tnx

Answer (score 2):

because of your comment in my previous answer, i post this answer.

for align arrow icon to right, just wrap google plus section by `Left` tag.

```js
<Card>
  <View style={styles.containerTextHeader}>
       <Text style={styles.infoTextHeader}>Tenant Details</Text>
 </View>
 <CardItem>
     <Left>
       <Icon active name="logo-googleplus" />
       <Text>First Name</Text>
     </Left>
     <Right>
       <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
     </Right>
 </CardItem>
</Card>
```

for defining click function on button, you can wrap card item by any button such as this:

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => //your function}
    <CardItem>
    </CardItem>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to have right before the "arrow-forward" a text with the placeholder style? My goal is "ICON First Name       Jonh Smith >>". I would like a different style for "Jonh Smith", something like placeholder style.